# Java, passing an array into a method and attempting to return index, various issues arise

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, methods, parameter-passing

I have to create two arrays with team names and team scores, pass them through to separate methods, find the minimum and maximum values, print out a list of the teams and score with the highest and lowest score represented. Cool, did almost all of that just fine.

```
import java.util.*;

public class asgn6 {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        System.out.print("\nHow many teams do you want to enter: ");
        int teamNum = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        String[] team = new String[teamNum];
        int[] score = new int[teamNum];
        for(int i=0; i<teamNum; i++) {
            System.out.println("Team " + ((i)+1) + ": \nEnter team's name:\t");
            team[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter team's score (400-1000):");
            score[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<teamNum; i++) {
            System.out.println(team[i] + " " + +score[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Losing team: " + team[minIndex] + " score: " + score[minIndex]);
        System.out.println("Winning team: " + team[maxIndex] + " score: " + score[maxIndex]);
    }
    public static int findIndexOfMin (int[] score) {
        int smallestValue = score[0];
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++){
            if (score[i] <= smallestValue){
                smallestValue = score[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }
    public int findIndexOfMax(int[] score) {
        
        int largestValue = score[0];
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++){
            if (score[i] >= largestValue){
                largestValue = score[i];
                maxIndex  = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
}
```

The problem begins when I try to pass the index from each method back to main. It tells me that the variables of `minIndex` and `maxIndex` cannot be resolved. I try to resolve those numerous ways, but it usually just results in them defaulting to being the same value (which as far as I can see should not be the case), or just being plain wrong in some way. I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Nowhere are you calling your `findIndexOfMin()` and `findIndexOfMax()` methods.

Comment: You wonderful person you, that fixed it. Calling it and wrapping them main references or whatever fixed it.  I'll post the final results so someone can maybe get inspiration. Thanks again friend.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Robby Cornelissen. I failed to actually call the methods and reference the returned index properly.

```
findIndexOfMin(score);
findIndexOfMax(score);
System.out.println("Losing team: " + team[findIndexOfMin(score)] + " score: " + score[findIndexOfMin(score)]);
System.out.println("Winning team: " + team[findIndexOfMax(score)] + " score: " + score[findIndexOfMax(score)]);

aa 67
ss 45
dd 78
ff 13
gg 90

The gg have the highest score of => 90 and the ff have the lowest score of =>13
```

That did the trick. The indexes are returned and then display the correct values for the referenced lists.